# Using Dagger 2 between android modules (aar)

Tags: android, dependency-injection, module, aar, dagger-2

The context:

- I Have two modules in my project: A and B
- The module A depends on module B
- The module B have a Dagger 2 dependency defined into my gradle file
- The module A have components that use @modules classes from Module B to provide the intances to use with dependency injection

The problem:
The Dagger 2 processor, responsible to code generation, doesn't create any classes necessaries to provide the dependencies defined on @module classes located on module B.

The doubts:

- Is not possible to use Dagger 2 between modules?
- Have another way to solve my problem?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31865368/2413303

Comment: @pablobaldez Did you succeed to link a module which depends on Dagger 2?

Comment: @surlac Yes. I will report here how i did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an way to do that. I have to create a subcomponent responsible to expose the @provide methods from my @module classes. So, my components from Module A have dependencies from subcomponents defined on Module B. Easy